# jquery width of ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**var $vlinks width are returnig zero  width**

Please suggest solution to find vlink width

here is the relevent code:

```
var $btn = $('nav.greedy button');

  var $vlinks = $('nav.greedy .links');

  var $hlinks = $('nav.greedy .hidden-links');


  var numOfItems = 0;

  var totalSpace = 0;


  var closingTime = 1000;``

  var breakWidths = [];


  $vlinks.children().outerWidth(function(i, w) 
{


    totalSpace += w;

    numOfItems += 1;

    breakWidths.push(totalSpace);
  });
```

this is my html structure of page and i want to get ul li width and store in breakwidth array

```
 <div class="nav" style="background-color: #f9f9f9;">
        <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">

           <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Side Panel" ng-click="openSideNavPanel()" hide-gt-xs show-sm id="mobile-side-nav">
              <md-icon class="md-default-theme mobile-side-nav" class="material-icons" style="color:#4bbb85">&#xE5D2;</md-icon>
           </md-button>
           <!-- Logo -->
           <a ng-href="" class="logos">
           <img src="style/img/assets/logo.jpg"> <span class="logo-label-city">Delhi</span>
           </a>
          <span flex></span>
          <!--  <md-button  ng-click="showAdvanced($event)">
              <span style="color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);text-decoration:none">Login</span>
           </md-button> -->
           <a href=""><span style="color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);text-decoration:none;font-size:0.7em">Login</span></a>

           <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="Search" ng-click="searchClick()">

             <md-icon class="material-icons  searchIcon" style="color:#4bbb85; padding-top: 3;">search</md-icon>

           </md-button>
        <div id="searchBox" style="display:none">
          <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-accent" >
                     <input class="inputSearch" ng-model="searchInput" placeholder="Search SoCity" >
                  </md-input-container>
        </div>

        </div>

                    <md-divider class="divider" hide-xs></md-divider>
                   <!--  <div id="fixedTop" hide-xs>
                      <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
                        <li ng-repeat = "interest in interests |limitTo:10" ><a href=""  aria-label="interest.key" ng-click="interest_click($index,interest.key)" md-no-ink id="{{$index}}">{{interest.name}}</a></li>
                         <li><a href="" ng-click="toogleDextopDropDown()"><span>More</style></a>
          <ul id="dextop-dropdown">

                <li ng-repeat = "interest in interests |limitTo:15:10"><a href="" ng-bind="interest.name" aria-label="interest.key" ng-click="interest_click($index +11,interest.key)" md-no-ink id="{{$index +11}}"></a></li></ul></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div> -->
                    <nav class='greedy' id="parent">

  <ul class='links'>
    <li ng-repeat = "interest in interests |limitTo:10" ><a href=""  aria-label="interest.key" ng-click="interest_click($index,interest.key)" md-no-ink id="{{$index}}">{{interest.name}}</a></li>
  </ul>
  <button>More</button>
  <ul class='hidden-links hidden'></ul>
</nav>
        </md-toolbar>
      </div>
```

thank you all

Comment: Check [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

`outerWidth(function() { })` appears to be for setting the width according to https://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Try this instead, looping over the entries:

```
var $btn = $('nav.greedy button');
var $vlinks = $('nav.greedy .links');
var $vlinkChildren = $vlinks.children();
var $hlinks = $('nav.greedy .hidden-links');
var numOfItems = $vlinkChildren.length;
var totalSpace = 0;
var closingTime = 1000;
var breakWidths = [];
$vlinkChildren.each(function() {
    var width = $(this).outerWidth();
    totalSpace += width;
    breakWidths.push(totalSpace);
});
```

If this doesn't solve it, you need to provide a sample of the html structure you are dealing with.

Comment: Hi jedifans thank you for giving answer but i am not geting width of ul li

Comment: Is the above code executing after angular has populated the li's?

Comment: No ,above code is not executing after angular has populated th li's

Comment: Ok. As there are no li's to examine when the above code runs, there will be no widths found. I'm not sure how but you need to get that code to run after angular makes the li elements.